# Can 'being' be omitted in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Their work is still far from **(being)** finished.

Can 'being' be omitted in the sentence above?

Comment: Yes, it can; [in fact, it's much more common to omit it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+from+finished%2Cfar+from+being+finished&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfar%20from%20finished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfar%20from%20being%20finished%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: That linked-to question isn't related to this question AT ALL!!!